# Stop Form Freeze When Downloading String From Website

Tags: .net, vb.net, freeze, webclient

In my application, I have a web client that is supposed to download a string from a website. It downloads quite a large amount of text, about 20 lines or so. However, when I download the text, the GUI freezes while downloading and then resumes after it's done downloading. How can I prevent this?

I am using Visual Basic 2010, .NET 4.0, Windows Forms, and Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Use an AJAX call to fetch the string asynchronously. For more help, post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) for this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            return wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
        }
    })
.ContinueWith((t,_)=>
    {
            textBox1.Text = t.Result;
    }, 
    null,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

*PS: Although you can use this template for any method that doesn't have async version, WebClient.DownloadString do have one, so I would choose Karl Anderson's answer*

Comment: That is sexy right there. There are Async methods for `WebClient` too.

Comment: Are you serious that what I use!

Comment: @DonA If it is about my deleted comment: I thought you were talking about *async/await (WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync)*

Answer (score 0):

Do time intensive tasks in worker threads and not on the GUI thread. This will prevent the event loop from freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `DownloadStringAsync`, this will fire the request from the UI thread, but it will not block the thread, because it is an asynchronous request. Here is an example of using `DownloadStringAsync`:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub AlertStringDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
        '  Did the request go as planned (no cancellation or error)?
        If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
            ' Do something with the result here
            'e.Result
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim wc As New WebClient

        AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf AlertStringDownloaded

        wc.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))
    End Sub
End Class
```